# Showing that a map $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is well-defined

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I have a map $g: \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $g([0]) = 0$ and $g([1]) = 1$. I'm trying to show that this map is well-defined, so I think I need to show that
$$ 
[x] = [y] \implies g([x]) = g([y]). 
$$
Or do I need to show that if $x \sim y$, then $g([x]) = g([y])$? The first statement above is the definition of the map, but the second one I wrote down is a bit more involved. It would boil down to saying that if $x \sim y$, then $2 \mid x - y$ so $2k = x - y$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $y = x + 2k$. If $x$ is even, then $y$ is even. If $x$ is odd, then $y$ is odd. (I don't know if there's a simpler way to see that then by just plugging in $2m$ and $2m+1$ for $x$.) As $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, they should get mapped to the same output under $g$.

I feel like I'm repeating myself and getting back to "it follows from the definition of the map." I know there is definitely something here that requires checking, but I'm not certain of exactly what it is.

Comment: There is nothing to prove there, apart perhaps from the fact that $[0]\ne[1]$. I am confused by your problem and suspect a misunderstanding/typo.

Comment: @StinkingBishop It's my understanding that when I define a function on equivalence classes I need to prove that the map is well-defined, which amounts to proving that if $[x] = [y]$, then $g([x]) = g([y])$. I'm giving this as an example in a problem that asked for an example of a certain function.

Comment: When you define the function on equivalence classes *by using representatives*, then you need to prove that your choice does not depend on the choice of the representative. For example, if you tried to define $g([n]):=n\pmod 2$, then fair enough. But you are not doing that in your question: you are directly mapping $[0]$ to $0$ and $[1]$ to $1$, and that's that. You are not using representatives.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think I still don't fully understand, because $[0] = [2] = [4]$, and I'm picking a representative, $0$, of the class to define the map $g$.

Comment: Yes, $[0]=[2]$ but because you've never specified what $[2]$ needs to map to, you need not prove that it maps to the same thing as $[0]$. As I said, the only thing you need to prove (or take on faith) is that, indeed, $\mathbb Z/2$ is a $2$-element set consisting of $[0]$ and $[1]$. Then you can map those two elements into whatever you want. (Say,$[0]\mapsto 7$ and $[1]\mapsto -3$,  or you can take a different set $\{\text{apple, pear, orange}\}$ as a co-domain and map $[0]\mapsto\text{apple}, [1]\mapsto\text{orange}$ etc.)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. If I hadn't proved beforehand that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is a set of distinct equivalence classes $[0], [1], \ldots, [n-1]$, there may be something more to prove here and, frankly, the map may not be fully specified. But because we know what $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is, there isn't any such ambiguity here. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yep, that is it. Glad to help!