# Checking the homomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S^1$ is well-defined?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I'm not sure if it is necessary given my definition of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to check whether the map $f: \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S^1$ given by $f(t) = \exp(2\pi i t)$ is well-defined. A related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432563/showing-that-a-map-mathbbz-2-to-mathbbz-is-well-defined?noredirect=1#comment9278091_4432563) where I learned that I only need to check well-definedness if I define a function based on the representatives of equivalence classes.

My definition of the group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the set $[0,1)$ together with the operation of addition mod $1$. This map technically uses a representative of the class, $t$, but it doesn't explicitly define $[0,1)$ as a set of equivalence classes, even though I know that the element $0$ is, secretely, the equivalence class of all integers (or, at least, I could have defined $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ in such a way).

Is it necessary to check that $f$ is well-defined? Or am I correct that because there is only one "representative" for each class in $[0,1)$, there isn't any ambiguity? I assume the same is true when I define $\mathbb{Z}/n$ as the set of elements $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ and define addition mod $n$, instead of as equivalence classes.

Comment: I think your question is the identification of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the induced addition  with $[0,1)$ equipped with the mod 1 addition. The well-definess of $f$ on [0,1) is trivial.

Comment: @AnnieGurad Can you explain what you mean by trivial in this case?

Comment: The well-definess of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is necessary to check, which means you need to check that two elements in the same equivalence will be send to the same value.But [0,1) is just a "set" rather a "equivalence class", the definition of $f$ on this set has no ambiguity at all.  You may identify them by default, but it seems that this is actually the point, i.e.you need to prove that the definition of $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},+)$ coincide with  $( [0,1),+_{mod 1})$.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, the map $[0,1) \to S^1$ doesn't require checking well-definedness, but if I wanted to prove that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong [0,1)$, I certainly would need it. Is that correct? That makes a lot of sense if so.

Comment: Exactly. And the latter case is the same, the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ itself has nothing realted to "equivalence class".   It is the definition of "equivalence class" or "representative elements"  or something makes you relate them together. But this is just the well-definess require checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The mapping $[0,1)\to S^1$, $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$ is well-defined, and assuming you've already seen some basic complex analysis there's no need to go deeper into this. But for the sake of completeness, here goes. One typically defines the exponential as the mapping $\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$, $z\mapsto\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$. One can obviously restrict the domain to get a mapping $[0,1)\to\Bbb{C}$, $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$. The only question is whether $e^{2\pi i t}$ actually lies in $S^1$, and of course the answer is yes (clear once you know $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ and $\overline{e^z}=e^{\overline{z}}$, since then $|e^{2\pi i t}|^2=e^{2\pi i t}e^{-2\pi i t}=e^0=1$).
- Now, if you *define* $\Bbb{R}/ \Bbb{Z}$ to be the set $[0,1)$, then there's nothing more involved in showing $f$ is a well-defined function. Having said this, one typically defines $\Bbb{R}/ \Bbb{Z}$ as a quotient group, so set theoretically it's not equal to $[0,1)$. Of course it's very trivial to establish the bijection $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\cong [0,1)$; so if you start with this quotient definition of $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$, then showing that $f$ is a well-defined mapping takes just slightly more effort (actually this is a matter of complex analysis, in that it uses the periodicity of the 'imaginary' exponential).
- A separate question which arises (though you didn't ask) is whether or not $f$ is actually a homomorphism from the abelian group $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$ into $S^1$ (does it preserve the group operations). Proving this directly is not too bad though you may have to deal with some small amount of case work (regardless of which definition you adopt). But the standard way of proving that a map from a quotient group to some other group is a homomorphism is to first consider a map from the not-quotiented group, and then investigate its kernel. Explicitly, consider $F:\Bbb{R}\to S^1$, $F(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$. This is a well-defined mapping, and it's a homomorphism because of the properties of complex exponentials. The  $2\pi$-periodicity of the exponential (a complex-analysis fact) means that $\ker F=\Bbb{Z}$. Therefore, (universal property of quotient groups) there is a well-defined group homomorphism $f:\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\to S^1$ such that for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$, we have $F(t)= f([t])$, where $[t]\in\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$ denotes the equivalence class.
- Similar remarks in the $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ case. If set theoretically you define this to be $\{0,\dots, n-1\}$, there's nothing to be checked in terms of well-definition of functions having this as the domain, because there are no equivalence classes to be dealt with in this approach. What does require a small verification is the equivalence between this definition and the usual equivalence-class definition of $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. Also, typically, we're not just interested in the functions with these domains; we're interested in whether or not they're group homomorphisms (and for that the standard way is the one I described above, using the universal property).

Comment: Extra facts: the map $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\to S^1$ is not just a well-defined function, but it is also a group isomorphism. Furthermore, once you equip the appropriate topologies (quotient topology on $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$ and subspace topology on $S^1\subset \Bbb{C}$), this map also becomes a homeomorphism (continuous with continuous inverse). So, this map is about as nice as things get.